# How can I share a git stash?

Tags: git

Is there a way to share a stash in git?

I work on a number of machines, and often want to be able to move my current working state from one to another.

I'm looking for a way that I can push/pull a stash from one clone to another, and have it appear either as the stash for the other clone, or as an apparent remote branch.
I'm not expecting that the former will necessarily work if the remote already has stash of its own though.

Given that stash is, in effect, already a branch with commits on it (apparently), I'm not looking for solutions along the lines of "commit each stash to a branch and then share those" - I've already got many, many, branches.
I'm therefore looking for the [refspec](http://iissnan.com/progit/html/en/ch9_5.html) or similar that I can use to control the push/pulling.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The stash is just `stash` or `refs/stash`, which you can push to a remote branch:

```
git push origin stash@{2}:refs/heads/otherstash
```

Git will refuse pushing directly to `refs/stash`, however. Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to push entire *reflogs*, where previous stashes are stored.

Comment: `git push origin $(for sha in $(git rev-list -g stash); do echo $sha:refs/heads/stash_$sha; done)` should do nicely for all stashes; See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5248758/85371

Answer (score 23):

It's not as well integrated as a `git push` but to avoid creating branches, I use `git stash show -p > change.patch` (after stashing the changes) or even `git diff --cached > change.patch` to create a patch that I `git apply change.patch` on the next machine I work from.

With this solution at least, if many files are altered in your current working state, everything is contained in a single data unit.

Comment: Yes.. but how ? git stash -p only asks me interactively about every hunk - then spits long line that I don't understand. Where is that "patch" I can take with me to another machine? and what is the git diff--cached? and how do you use git apply? Can you elaborate just a little further please?

Comment: I detailed and corrected my answer

Comment: @Neo thanks for sharing this solution.  I am trying to integrate this into my workflow, but am having trouble incorporating new, untracked files using this approach.  Do you know of any way of getting new files into the `change.patch` file?  This command stashes new, untracked files `git stash --all` or `git stash --include-untracked`, but I cannot get the new, untracked files to show up in the patch file when issuing `git stash show -p > change.patch`.  Any ideas?  Thanks again for providing this path 

Comment: nevermind, I finally remembered how to properly use `git diff --cached` and that works perfectly with new, untracked files.  Thanks again for this neat trick.  :)

Comment: in case it helps others:
1. `git add .` 2. `git diff --staged > ~/some_synced_folder/change.patch` 3. (on another sync'd computer) `git apply ~/some_synced_folder/change.patch`

Answer (score 6):

You can make patch and send it to someone. the thing you they have to do is to apply it.

```
git diff >> file.diff
```

Comment: Note this will only work for objects that generate a diff; beware of "Binary files differ" in the output.

Comment: Can u add how to apply the patch